# Notification in Android

Tags: android, notifications

what do you prefer for making a notification on specific date and time... in [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) I can't find where to define date and time...

However is there any other way to handle this notifications?

Comment: Look thoroughly at that documentation, especially at "The Basics"->"2.Instantiate the Notification"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class it can help you scheduling events.